# Add Menu Item in Luma

Tags: magento2, menu, luma-theme

How can I add a Menu item in Magento 2 default Luma Theme ?

[image]

Comment: You can create child category or default category and then, it will display there.

Comment: Thanks @RohanHapani. What should I do if I would like to add a Static word ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static menu is not good practise. You should create sub menu in default category.

But, For static menu you need to overrride **topmenu.phtml** at `app/design/frontend/<vendor_name>/<theme_name>/Magento_Theme/templates/html/`

You can copy from your `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/topmenu.phtml` and paste in your theme phtml like below way :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Top menu for store
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
 */
?>
<?php $columnsLimit = $block->getColumnsLimit() ?: 0; ?>
<?php $_menu = $block->getHtml('level-top', 'submenu', $columnsLimit) ?>

<nav class="navigation" data-action="navigation">
    <ul data-mage-init='{"menu":{"responsive":true, "expanded":true, "position":{"my":"left top","at":"left bottom"}}}'>
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_menu ?>
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getChildHtml() ?>
        <li class="level0 nav-7 category-item last level-top ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
            <a href="#" class="level-top ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-8" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
                <span>New Menu</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```